# (This action wont work on multiple selections) When try to copy and paste values

Tags: excel

I have issue with some of Excel files
I can't copy or paste any single value to another sheet also even I tried to add new sheet in same file ..
the message error is (This action wont work on multiple selections)
by the way the files was work so fine!
I tried to delete and re-downloads the files from main source and still the problem ON..

Any help?

Comment: This behavior happens when you are trying to copy cells from more than one column and more than one row, but not contiguous. Such as copying Cell A1 and B4 by holding down the CTRL button. Excel doesn't like that. Perhaps your control key is stuck. https://superuser.com/questions/956049/control-key-acts-as-if-it-is-stuck-periodically

Comment: Hi @Isolated unfortunately It happens even if I copy only one cell..

Comment: But something thinks you are trying to copy more than one. Have you tried going thru the remedies offered by that other page?

Comment: @Isolated sorry may you explain more, what do you mean by remedies?

Comment: @Stax No hidden or merged cells

Answer (score 0):

I think all the sheets are selected when you are copying.

Right click on any sheet number at the bottom and click Ungroup. This should solve your problem most probably.

[image: Ungroup sheet]

Comment: Can u upload your file